# SSLError (read operation timed out) instead of timeout when PUT using Requests

Tags: rest, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to do various REST requests to a piece of equipment using the Requests package.
It is working, but on some requests, like PUTs, I'm getting a SSLError, instead of a timeout that I'm specifying.

I have the code set up to retry, up to 5 times, doubling the timeout each time (1,2,4,8, 16, 32), and if I treat the SSLError as a timeout, then it will eventually pass. Here's an example, and you can see the SSLError is occurring at the pace of the timeout interval:

```
2013-12-10 19:41:13.208 22294 DEBUG client [-] PUT: Request for https://192.168.200.20/api/v1/global/host-name headers {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-auth-token': u'...omitted...'} payload {'host-name': 'TestHost'}
2013-12-10 19:41:13.209 22294 INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool [-] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.200.20
2013-12-10 19:41:14.253 22294 ERROR client [-] EXCEPTION The read operation timed out  <<< SSL Error
2013-12-10 19:41:14.255 22294 INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool [-] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.200.20
2013-12-10 19:41:16.301 22294 ERROR client [-] EXCEPTION The read operation timed out
2013-12-10 19:41:16.302 22294 INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool [-] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.200.20
2013-12-10 19:41:20.346 22294 ERROR client [-] EXCEPTION The read operation timed out
2013-12-10 19:41:20.348 22294 INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool [-] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.200.20
2013-12-10 19:41:25.845 22294 DEBUG requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool [-] "PUT /api/v1/global/host-name HTTP/1.1" 204 0 _make_request /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:289
2013-12-10 19:41:25.846 22294 DEBUG client [-] PUT: Completed [204]
```

As you can see the EXCEPTION log messages are the SSLError errors, but they are timeouts as they map to the timeout I specify.

In python, I'm doing this for the calls (it's spread out so here is the gist of it):

```
url = ('https://%(host)s/api/v1/%(resource)s' %
       {'host': self.host, 'resource': resource})
...
response = self._request(method, url, try_num, timeout=timeout,
                         headers=headers, data=payload)
...
def _request(self, method, url, attempt, **kwargs):
    ...
    try:
        response = requests.request(method, url, verify=False, **kwargs)
    except Timeout:
        self.status = wexc.HTTPRequestTimeout.code
        LOG.debug(_("%(method)s: Request timeout" ...)
    except SSLError as se:
        LOG.error("EXCEPTION %s", se)
        self.status = wexc.HTTPRequestTimeout.code
```

If I don't handle the SSL error, then it gets caught as a ConnectionError.  Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

I have this hack in place, but would like to know why I get the SSL error.

Comment: Did some digging trying to find the exception. Looks like in urllib3/connectionpool.py, it calls conn.request() and then conn.getresponse() and it appears that the getresponse() call is the one where the exception is thrown. I haven't found the source yet though.

Comment: What version of Requests are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I'm using requests 1.2.0 and python 2.7.3 (although I'll need to try this with 2.6 and 3.3 at some point).

Comment: Actually, the timeout happens on POST and DELETE requests too, but with the H/W I'm communicating with the delay is 1-2 secs, versus 4-8 seconds for PUT requests (another issue I need to investigate).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lukasa! You're question prompted me to investigate the version. I installed requests 2.1.0 and now I see Timeout exceptions, instead of SSLError exceptions, which is what I expected to see.